# flexdashboard not showing all the columns of my dataset

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

My dataset is missing most of the columns when I try to knit. The html page shows only 2 columns, but my dataset has 11. The output shown in Rstudio after running the chunk is fine, the dataset is shown properly without any missing data:

Dataset shown in Rstudio (without issues):
[image]

Dataset shown on html page (misssing columns):

[image]

````
---
title: "Video Games Salse Analysis"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---


```{r}
# checking column and data overview
games_data <- import("vgsales.csv")
games_data
```
````

I tried to increase the data-width and change the vertical_layout but they did not help.

Comment: Hi, can you share your .csv file?

Comment: I don't think I can attach a csv file here. but here is the link to the dataset that I used. https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gregorut/videogamesales?resource=download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the size of the dataset. If you use the `kable()` function from the `knitr` library it prints all the columns but it takes awhile to render. Replace your last line (games_data) with the following.

```
knitr::kable(games_data)
```

Be sure to install the knitr package if you haven't already.`install.packages('knitr')`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. I want to upvote your answer but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. sorry:(

Comment: No problem! Welcome to SO! You should be able to accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to my answer to let others know this solution worked.